# How to add a jar to the boot classpath in java 9

Tags: java, classpath, java-9, bootclasspath

In my application that runs on java 8, I am using `-bootclasspath:p` to add a jar to the boot classpath. In java 9, the option is removed. What is the alternative to do the same in java 9?

Comment: `javac -bootclasspath` works as before when targeting JDK 8 or older .`java -Xbootclasspath/a` to append to the boot class path works as before.

Comment: I guess you mean `-Xbootclasspath/a` JVM option which I could confirm is still present in the java options of 9.0.1. Or maybe i misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use `-Xbootclasspath/a`. Please refer to the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html) which states:-

> The boot class path has been mostly removed in this release. The java
>   `-Xbootclasspath`  and `-Xbootclasspath/p` options have been removed.
>
> The `javac -bootclaspath` option can only be used when compiling to JDK 8 or
>   older. The system property `sun.boot.class.path` has been removed.
>
> Deployments that rely on overriding platform classes for testing
>   purposes with `-Xbootclasspath/p` will need to changed to use the
>   `--patch-module` option that is documented in [JEP 261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261).
>
> The `-Xbootclasspath/a` option is unchanged.

Comment: Thank you. I was using -Xbootclasspath/p . 
Shall change it to -Xbootclasspath/a . Hope there is no difference other than that the former appends to the beginning of the classpath and the later at the end.

Comment: I am having same issue with java 11 and even -Xbootclasspath/a is not working. Does anyone know any workaround please..

Answer (score 0):

`-bootclasspath:p` add classes from jar to the begin of default bootstrap class path (prepended). It isn't longer supported in JVM 9 or greater.

`-bootclasspath:a` add classes from jar to the end of default bootstrap class path (appended). This option is supported in JVM 9 or greater.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/JRCLR/optionx.htm#i1021218

In my case when I declare variables in this order:

> JAVA_OPTS="$SOME_OPT"
>
> JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:../agent.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:../agent-boot.jar $JAVA_OPTS"

I catch classNotFoundException. And when I reverse order:

> JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:../agent.jar -Xbootclasspath/a:../agent-boot.jar $JAVA_OPTS"
>
> JAVA_OPTS="$SOME_OPT"

ClassNotFound exception disappear.