# How to add a jar to the boot classpath in java 11

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, classpath, bootclasspath

In my application which is running on Java 8 I used third party library which is using org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager So I added this jar in bootclass path and it works fine. But when migrate to java 11 either -Xbootclasspath/a or -Xbootclasspath/p is not working and I can not start my application.

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/a:D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar
```

I found [How to add a jar to the boot classpath in java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148607/how-to-add-a-jar-to-the-boot-classpath-in-java-9) answer. But it is not working for java 10 or 11.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I would think the `-Xbootclasspath/a` should work. Is there an error you're seeing or do you have a way to reproduce it?

Comment: Thanks @JamesR.Perkins for your reply. It can easily reproduce by adding below options to standalone.conf.bat ; set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/a:D:/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.4.Final.jar

Comment: Are you using an agent? FWIW WildFly 10 has not been tested with Java 11.

Comment: yes I'm trying to use Azure ApplicationInsight java agent.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the workaround in [LOGMGR-218](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/LOGMGR-218?focusedCommentId=13669721&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13669721). Note though WildFly 10 is not really tested on Java 11. You might want to consider WildFly 15.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

(1) For me replacing  `-Xbootclasspath/p` with  `-Xbootclasspath/a` - **Did not work**

(2) Then I tried to remove the whole line as this has been suggested by others <s>`-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p: <path_to_jboss_logmanager>/jboss-logmanager-<version>.jar`</s>  - **Did not work**

(3) Then I **also** removed the logmanager from `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=`<s>org.jboss.logmanager</s>`"`  and **then it worked**!

So only the combination of 2+3 finally worked.

Answer (score -2):

In `JAVA jdk 11` and above, if you are developing a java console app then you only need to set the `PATH` environment variable. You do not need to set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.