# Ignore -Xbootclasspath/p command line flag with Java 11+

Tags: java, java-11, alpn

Is there a way to ignore the `-Xbootclasspath/p` flag inside the java command line with Java 11 withoiut removing it such that the same command line can be used for Java 8 and Java 11?
The command line I am using is the following with ALPN.

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/alpn/alpn-boot/8.1.12.v20180117/alpn-boot-8.1.12.v20180117.jar -jar the-bundle.jar
```

I get the following error.

```
-Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I already tried `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions` without success (I get the same error).

Comment: Ideally, you should be replacing the VM argument. What doesn't work with `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions`? Please share the error. Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48148607/how-to-add-a-jar-to-the-boot-classpath-in-java-9

Comment: I have added the error. It doesn't change the behavior when adding `-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions` before or after `-Xbootclasspath/p:`.

Comment: This looks a patch to add ALPN to JDK 8, I assume it makes no sense to attempt to patch JDK 9 or newer as the support is built-in.

Comment: I totally agree ALPN is not needed anymore for Java 9+. However I would like to keep the command line compatible with Java 8 and Java 9+. It would be nice the parameter is just ignored instead of crashing the JVM.