# Patch jdk.unsupported module in Java 17

Tags: java, javac, java-module, java-17, patch-module

For various reasons, I need to continue to use some `sun.misc` classes in Java 17, specifically the BASE64Decoder class. (The algorithm used by the class has some specific behavior that other base 64 decoders do not reproduce.) I'm planning to use the rt.jar file, provided in OpenJDK 8, as the source for these classes, and I'm patching the `jdk.unsupported` module.

With the following example class, I'm able to compile it using `javac --patch-module=jdk.unsupported=/path/to/rt.jar TestDecoder.java`

```java
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class TestDecoder {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(new byte[0]));
  }
}
```

It [seems that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385547/why-is-the-java-11-runtime-ignoring-my-jar-containing-sun-misc-classes/56409662#56409662) in versions of Java prior to Java 17, it was possible to then run it with patch-module:

```
java --patch-module=jdk.unsupported=/path/to/rt.jar \ 
     -cp /path/to/rt.jar \
     TestDecoder.class
```

However, in Java 17, this fails with `java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module jdk.unsupported contains package java.time.zone, module java.base exports package java.time.zone to jdk.unsupported`. It seems like since java.base exports to jdk.unsupported, it's not possible to patch the jdk.unsupported module. Is there any way to work around this?

Versions:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
$ javac --version
javac 17.0.2
```

(The Java 11 version of this question is [Why is the Java 11 runtime ignoring my jar containing sun.misc classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385547/why-is-the-java-11-runtime-ignoring-my-jar-containing-sun-misc-classes), this is *not* a duplicate of that question.)

Comment: “The algorithm used by the class has some specific behavior that other base 64 decoders do not reproduce.”  Are you sure?  [java.util.Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.html) has three decoder factory methods.  What other base64 variations are there?

Comment: "It seems like since java.base exports to jdk.unsupported, it's not possible to patch the jdk.unsupported module". I think the issue here is split packages. i.e. 2 modules can not both define a package with the same name.

Comment: @VGR The java.util.Base64 MIME decoder is the one most similar, but the sun.misc.BASE64Decoder class has some idiosyncracies that make some strings work for it but fail to parse with the java.util.Base64 MIME decoder. For one example, "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKxhT:Dqw41vO7TqahhN/epcK7Sk=" successfully parses with the Sun implementation, but errors with "Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit" in the java.util implementation.

Comment: Why is there a `:` in your base 64 string?

Comment: Because sun.misc.BASE64Encoder put it there! I’m not sure why it produced invalid base 64, but unfortunately I need to parse it.

Comment: “*Because sun.misc.BASE64Encoder put it there*” So, in other words, you “need” to use the sun.misc decoder, because you are using the sun.misc encoder…

Comment: @Holger Dealing with maintaining legacy data. :) I'm only using the Decoder now, not the Encoder, but I still have the old data that I have to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is split packages. i.e. you can't have 2 modules that define the same package (java.time.zone in this case).

If you want to go the `--patch-module` route, you can not use the whole `rt.jar`. You will have to create a jar file with just the classes in `sun.misc` that you need.

For the base 64 encoder/decoder, it seems that at least `BASE64Decoder`, `BASE64Encoder`, `CharacterDecoder`, `CharacterEncoder`, and `CSStreamExhausted` are needed, all in the `sun.misc` package. If I create a jar with just those classes, and use that jar as an argument to `--patch-module`, I'm able to decode the string from your comment. (but, more classes might be needed for a more complex use case. I didn't test that far).

---

But, I'll also note that, as tgdavies pointed out, your string is not a valid base 64 string, according to the alphabet table in the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-25 (the same spec followed by the MIME encoder/decoder). The `:` is illegal, and it is ignored by the decoder, which means the trailing `=` used for padding is causing issue (you can also remove the `=` at the end to get the string to decode).

I'd recommend trying to sanitize your base 64 string and using the public base 64 API. That will probably be less of a hassle to keep working in the long term.